# How to work with Grails Http sessions

Tags: http, session, grails

I'm new to Grails and I'm struggling with sessions..

In a controller, how do I check is the user has a valid session? In Java/Spring MVC, it's simple request.getSession(), so what's the convention in Grails?

How do I add/get values from the session?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails uses the same servlet API as Java EE, though it provides a few extra convenience methods. Within a Grails controller, taglib or GSP there are implicit variables `request` and `session` that refer to the current [HTTPServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and [HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html).

Here's an example of how Grails makes it slightly more convenient to work with these objects:

### Java

```
Object fooAttr = session.getAttribute("foo");
```

### Grails

```
def fooAttr = session["foo"]
```

Comment: How do you check to see if the request has an active session, and if it doesn't, how to create one?

Comment: exactly the same way you do it in Java, i.e. using the overloaded `request.getSession()` methods

Comment: @Dónal, could you make small example for this case?

Answer (score 3):

you can work with the "session" object

[grails session](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html)

Answer (score 1):

After the user logs in, set the value(username) in the session.
For example, your domain class is User.groovy. So in your login method in controller:, you can do:

```
def login()
{
    def u = new User()
    u.properties[
            'login',
            'password',
            ] = params        
    if(u.save())
    session.user = u
}
```

After that, whenever you want to check if the session is still on, just do

```
if(session.user != null)
//your code
```

Answer (score 0):

session object in grails has two methods i.e-getAttribute() and setAttribute() which can be used to get/set value in session.